# lags with calculation and groupby a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe below. I am trying to create lags for var1,var2, var3 by calculating
(var_n/ lag2(var_n))-2  (where n is 1,2,3)

below code works fine for lag2. But I need to perform the calculation grouped by "grp"

CODE:

lag=[2]

df=pd.concat([df]+[df.groupby('grp'['var1','var2','var3'].shift(x).add_prefix('lag'+str(x)) for x in lag],axis=1)

In a different approach I tried below but I am not able to apply group by:

yoy = [12]

columns_y = df.loc[:, 'var1':'var3']

for col in columns_y.columns:

```
for x in yoy: 
    columns_y.loc[:,col+"_yoy"] =(columns_y[col]/(columns_y[col].shift(x)))-1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'grp':['a','a','a','b','b','b'],'abc2':['l','m','n','p','q','r'], 'abc3':['x','y','z','a','b','c'],
    'var1':[20,30,20,40,50,90],'var2':[50,80,70,20,30,40],'var3':[50,80,70,20,30,40]})

lag = [2]
lags_df = pd.concat([
    df.groupby('grp')[[f'var{i+1}' for i in range(3)]]
    .shift(x)
    .add_prefix(f'lag{x}_')
    for x in lag
], axis=1)
print(pd.concat([df, lags_df], axis=1))
```

otuputs

```
  grp abc2 abc3  var1  var2  var3  lag2_var1  lag2_var2  lag2_var3
0   a    l    x    20    50    50        NaN        NaN        NaN
1   a    m    y    30    80    80        NaN        NaN        NaN
2   a    n    z    20    70    70       20.0       50.0       50.0
3   b    p    a    40    20    20        NaN        NaN        NaN
4   b    q    b    50    30    30        NaN        NaN        NaN
5   b    r    c    90    40    40       40.0       20.0       20.0
```

Comment: The below code is working for me but I am not able to apply group by 

yoy = [12] 

columns_y = df.loc[:, 'var1':'var3'] 

for col in columns_y.columns: 

     for x in yoy: columns_y.loc[:,col+"_yoy"] = (columns_y[col]/(columns_y[col].shift(x)))-1